# Google Adwords has disapproved my Campaign due to Malware, but I cleaned the code

Tags: node.js, google-ads-api, malware, malware-detection

I'm running a node.js app on a VPS and my advertising for that app was stopped, because Google Adwords has flagged my site for malicious software.

I've contacted them and they said it was because of an image that was sourced from a malicious site. https://jloog.com/images/medieval-clipart-cup-19.jpg

Now I've put that link there myself, so it was not injected or anything. I just wanted to use that image, which I found through Google Images. So, I didn't even upload it to my server.

The link has now been removed for over two weeks, but after resubmitting my campaigns for approval, my site is still being flagged for the same reason. I searched in the shell with grep in my entire project but that link is nowhere in my code.

So what is causing the problem and how can I resolve this situation?

Comment: This sounds like something you need to be talking to Google about, not us.

Comment: I'm gonna talk to them again and talk to a specialist next time. I thought maybe it had to do with something else perhaps. Like that it might take 4 weeks for google to register changes or whatever.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because customer support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that it took Google somehow a long time to rescrape my site > 1 month. I had issued my advertisements again, but that wasn't enough and didn't trigger rescraping. I eventually got an email back from customer service (after about 3 weeks after I told them I already removed the link) that it was finally resolved.

Comment: You are lucky, that the customer service even responded.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to resolve this issue is by calling Ads support directly. As a professional WordPress security expert, I have faced this issue a lot's time. After making the site clean secure, the client still complains that Google doesn't approve their site because malicious links exist.

Contacting Google ads support, they just send the link but never arrange to rescan or check the website manually.

Before that, make sure your website is really clean and those links don't exist!

Then they will truly rescan the site actually!!
It took 7 business days for me.
https://securewp.net/tutorial/google-ads-disapproved-malicious-or-unwanted-software/